# Initialize a parameter in a derived type

Tags: oop, fortran

I am still wrapping my head around Fortran with an "*object oriented*" flavor.

Is it possible to initialize a variable **in a derived type**, and what if I'd like that variable to be a `parameter`?

For example, a classic `animal`, `cat`, `bee` set of types that should set the number of legs of each animal:

**animal module**

```
module animal_module
    implicit none

    type, abstract :: animal
        private
        integer, public :: nlegs = -1
    contains
...
```

**cat module**

```
module cat_module
    use animal_module, only : animal
    implicit none

    type, extends(animal) :: cat
        private
        ! error here about redefining nlegs...
        integer, public :: nlegs = 4
...
```

I've found online the keyword `initial`, but my compiler (Intel) complains about the keyword with a syntax error.

## Addendum

I've tried a [custom constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262253/how-to-override-a-structure-constructor-in-fortran) but apparently I am unable to write one for derived types. This is my attempt, only on the **cat** type:

```
module cat_module
    use animal_module, only : animal
    implicit none

    type, extends(animal) :: cat
        private
        real :: hidden = 23.
    contains
        procedure :: setlegs => setlegs
        procedure :: speak
    end type cat

    interface cat
        module procedure init_cat
    end interface cat

contains

    type(cat) function init_cat(this)
        class(cat), intent(inout) :: this
        this%nlegs = -4
    end function init_cat
...

program oo
    use animal_module
    use cat_module
    use bee_module
    implicit none

    character(len = 3) :: what = "cat"
    class(animal), allocatable :: q

    select case(what)
    case("cat")
        print *, "you will see a cat"
        allocate(cat :: q)
...
    print *, "this animal has ", q%legs(), " legs."
```

As the `animal` type has `integer, public :: nlegs = -1`, I expected the `cat` to have `-4` legs, but alas, it's still `-1`.

Comment: The thing is, `cat` already has a member variable called `nlegs` by virtue of it being an extension of `animal`.  So the compiler ain't going to let you declare another member of the same name.  I think you'll have to hack your way to a constructor which sets `nlegs` for `cats` to `4`.

Comment: Are you trying to have a (named) constant of that derived type, or to have a component within an object a constant?

Comment: I’m trying to have a field common to all types that extend animal, in this example the number of legs.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree, although I don't really understand how they work.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question, explaining the difficulties you are having.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark it's probably too small to be qualified as a question per se, as I've written, the number of legs is equal to the value given in the abstract type, the `cat` constructor isn't being called (a `print` inside confirms this).

Comment: Constructors aren't called by anything other than an explicit reference to them: there's no "automatic construction on allocation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19214571/3157076) for a component to be a named constant.  Also, it isn't possible to declare a component of an abstract type and then define default initialization for its value in an extending type.  Attempting to redeclare the component with default initialization leads to the error of the question.

High Performance Mark's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612398/initialize-a-parameter-in-a-derived-type#comment103535588_58612398) offers one route: provide a [custom constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4262253/3157076) for each extending type setting the value appropriately.  You can further set the component to private for encapsulation or protection.

Alternatively, you can provide a "getter" type-bound procedure which references a named constant:

```
module animal_module
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: animal
   contains
     procedure(getter), deferred :: nlegs
  end type animal

  abstract interface
     integer function getter(creature)
       import animal
       class(animal) creature
     end function getter
  end interface

end module animal_module

module cat_module
  use animal_module, only : animal
  implicit none

  type, extends(animal) :: cat
   contains
     procedure :: nlegs => nlegs_cat
  end type cat

contains

  integer function  nlegs_cat(creature)
    class(cat) creature
    integer, parameter :: my_cat_has_legs=3
    nlegs_cat = my_cat_has_legs
  end function nlegs_cat

end module cat_module

  use cat_module
  implicit none

  class(animal), allocatable :: fido

  fido = cat()
  print*, "Fido has", fido%nlegs(), "legs"
end
```

Finally, `initial` is [not standard Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52663082/3157076) (and would have similar problems).

Comment: I've tried the custom constructor way, since it seems the most polished one, but apparently I am missing something in my understanding how constructors work in fortran.

Comment: Another question showing your constructor attempt may be the clearest way to address this.  You can link to your question here (mentioning the comments received) for context.

Comment: I have [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58668698/constructor-of-derived-types) as you suggested.